# The localization of the ring of regular functions at a smooth point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X=V(f)\subset\mathbb A^2$ be an integral affine plane curve(It means that $O(X)$ is integral and the transcendence degree of the fractional field of $O(X)$ over $k$ is $1$). Suppose that $P$ is a smooth point in $X$(Without loss of generality, we may assume that $P=(0,0)$. The smoothness is defined as the partial derivatives of $f$ at $P$ are not both zeros). Then show that $O_{X,P}$ is a discrete valuation ring.

This assertion is in the book Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups by Tamas Szamuely. The author said we may write $f=\phi(x)x+\psi(x,y)y$. The constant term of $\psi$ is $f_{y}'(P)$, which is nonzero. I can understand what the author said till this part.

Then he said that we may write $y=gx$, where $g$ is the image of $-\phi\psi^{-1}$ in $O_{X,P}$ and hence $M_P=(x)$, which I could not understand. He said it is from the properties of the equivalence of local Dedekind ring, local PID not a field and Noetherian local domain with nonzero principal maximal ideal. I could not find the relations between the properties he quoted and the assertion he made. Could anyone explain it for me?

Answer (score 1):

I have understood it. We have $\phi x+\psi y=0$ on $X$. By the assumption of $\psi$ we can know that $\psi(P)\neq0$. Hence we can write $y=gx$ for g being the image of $-\phi\psi^{-1}$ in $O_{X,P}$. So $M_P$ is generated by $x$. Then by the equivalence conditions of discrete valuation rings we can conclude that $O_{X,P}$ is a DVR.

Comment: Yes, the $\phi$ and $\psi$ seem quite mysterious at first, but he's basically just writing down the Taylor expansion of $f$ centered at the point $P$.